# unexpected token `elif'

Tags: bash, shell, solaris

here im trying to write shell that will work on specific dates,Sun Solaris 10 does not support new function but im keep getting `syntax error near unexpected token`elif'`

```
DAY_Word=$(date +%A)

Nomral_Day=$(date +%d)
MONTH=$(date +%m)

if [ "$Nomral_Day" -eq 01 ] || [ "$Nomral_Day" -eq 16 ] && [ "$MONTH" -ne 02 ]
then

###run integrity after

elif [ "$Nomral_Day" -eq 12 ] || [ "$Nomral_Day" -eq 28 ] && [ "$DAY_Word" = "Thursday" ] && [ "$MONTH" -ne 02 ]
then

### run integrity before

elif [ "$Nomral_Day" -eq 13 ] || [ "$Nomral_Day" -eq 29 ] && [ "$DAY_Word" != "Friday" ] && [ "$MONTH" -ne 02 ]
then

### run integrity before

elif [ "$Nomral_Day" -eq 25 ] && [ "$DAY_Word" = "Thursday" ] && [ "$MONTH" -eq 02 ]
then

## run integrity before

elif [ "$Nomral_Day" -eq 26 ] && [ "$DAY_Word" != "Friday" ] && [ "$MONTH" -eq 02 ]
then

## run integrity before

fi
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't omit the command between `then` and `elif`. You have to include a command.

Add the command `true` and your script should work.

Comment: How would `true` fix it?

Comment: @JL2210 add any command you like.  `true` doesn't do anything, so it's a good choice.

Comment: Ah. I understand. I thought the "can't have no command" was a southern United States thing. See my latest edit.

Comment: Often the command `:` is used as a placeholder in situations like this. Yes, a single colon is a valid shell command. It does nothing at all, and it's there for situations like this where a command is required by syntax, but you don't want to put any "real" command.